# VSCode - You don't have an extension for debugging HTML error

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I worked a lot with Visual Studio Code, but since yesterday on all my devices it says: *You don't have an extension for debugging HTML*.

After a few tries I deleted VSCode and re-installed it. It worked right but as soon that I close VSCode and re-open it, the error keeps showing.

I've noticed that when I close it there is a tiny update box. I've reinstalled it a few times but it keeps happening.

[image: error image]

Comment: They've just updated it and I too have the same problem. It's a bug and VSCode needs to sort it, and test more carefully next time(please). I click Find HTML Extension as it suggested and it STILL pops up. Quite annoying.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that it isn't my problem :)

Comment: ditto. Does it occur specifically if you press F5 to save? I press F5 to save and run (and to create a stage copy which is useful), but I found Code so hard to configure a debugger, I gave up and started monitoring the F5 globally (win API) in a separate app to launch my own debugger. If they are listening, it would be great if F5 (& other keys) can be easily configured, without JSon, to just run an exe. That way I can refresh the page in an existing tab in chrome. When they talk about HTML debuggers, they forget that the HTML page might be an include in ASP etc. Cheers

Comment: right now my solution was to reinstall an older version of visual studio code, and disabling automatic updates.

Comment: I took Angelo Gabriel Abrita's solution (last one below) and then I modified it as I described in the comment I added to that solution. Problem solved!

Answer (score 11):

Go to `RUN` and select `ADD Configuration...`

[image]

After select your browser and bingo!

Comment: And if you want it to do nothing, change `"type": "pwa-msedge",` (or chrome etc) to `"type": "pwa-node",` add the line `"runtimeExecutable": "c:\\none.bat",` and make that batch file a stub with just an echo line. I don't have node installed on my system,

Answer (score 5):

It seems `launch.json` file is missing. Go to `Run and Debug` and click `Create a launch.json`.

Comment: Worked for me! Pressing F5 used to prompt me to generate `launch.json` in a new project. Instead I was getting, "You don't have an extension for debugging C#." I didn't connect it to a missing `launch.json` until your answer. `Run` > `Add Configuration...` > `.NET Core` solved it. Maybe the prompt to generate the launch file was removed in a VS Code update...?

Answer (score 0):

Using launch.json didn't work for my html file. All I did was paste the path of the file into my browser and it worked fine for me.