# XML Debugger in VSCode

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, csproj

I have a csproj file that I believe is made for compiling numerous C# programs in the same directory, but I'm having trouble running it as I keep on being asked for a XML debugger. When VSCode asks to find an XML debugger, the options that it provides are not XML debuggers, and are not relevant. I've tried installing XML plugins such as XML by Red Hat and XML Tools by Josh Johnson, but neither seem to be recognized as a debugging tool. Listing either of those plugins as the default formatter through the settings JSON doesn't have any results either. I don't even see an XML environment, but I don't know if that is necessary. I've also tried reinstalling VSCode and deleting and reinstalling all of my plugins, but that hasn't generated any results. What do I need to do in order to run this file properly?

Please bear with me as I'm new to both XML and C#, having most of my coding experience in Python, just trying to fix some issues with some macros that were created at my job years before I started.

[Error I'm getting when trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9C0M.png)

.csproj file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{CC048C24-CAA0-48E8-95E9-A2EC5E1FF435}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>BOMLib</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>BOMLib</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EPPlus, Version=4.5.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\EPPlus.4.5.3.1\lib\net40\EPPlus.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="BOMItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BOMKeys.cs" />
    <Compile Include="IBOMFilter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BOMTemplate.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Internal\BOMLocationData.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Internal\StyleCopyTools.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Resources\BOMTemplate.xlsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: please share a screen shot of the prompt/issue.  As you say that does not make sense as XML is just a data format, not a programming language, so not sure what there is to "debug"

Comment: I've included a screenshot of the error I get when I try to run

Answer (score 0):

You don't run/debug the .csproj file.  You run/debug the .cs code file that contains the `Main` method.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67430297/vscode-you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-html-error) worked for me.
Go to Run > Add configuration > select your language